# I need to make a callback widget for my website. How can I do it?

Tags: voximplant

I have a lending website for selling stuff and I need to make a button which a client can click and the system should call them and connect to my support team. I made some research and found that Voximplant provides this functionality, but I can't figure it out. Anyone has some working solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Programmable callback template in the control panel:
https://manage.voximplant.com/marketplace/call-back